# Convert NVARCHAR Date to Date/Datetime Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

```
OrderCreatedDate
9/20/2013 12:01:59 AM
```

Data is imported from a CSV as `NVARCHAR`, I would like to convert this in to `date` or `datetime` format

However, if I try and import it as a date/datetime it mixes up the months/days on some of the records strangely

If I try and cast or convert I get the follow error:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

The date format is shown at the top of this post

thanks

Comment: What language is your SQL Server set to? Run `select @@language` and report the output

Comment: How do you import the data? The real solution is to specify the correct format for the CSV using your import tool. SSIS allows this, BULK INSERT too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data format is mdy, try this

```
set dateformat mdy

select cast(OrderCreatedDate as datetime) from table
```

Comment: thanks seems to have worked! you wouldn't happen to know how to how to set the dateformat when importing a csv so it converts it on import?

Comment: Hardcoding date formats is a *very* bad idea. At the very least, each CSV will have its own formatting. Another problem is that you will almost definitely forget to reset the dateformat at some point and end up with weird data from the rest of your batch

Comment: okay thing I need to try is to 'set dateformat mdy' in an asp dataview, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766854/asp-dataview-grid-set-dateformat-in-select-command, please could you help if you can

Answer (score 2):

@Madhivanan answer is valid. However I prefer converting using convert. Imagine doing this in a view. Every time the view is called, you will need to set the dateformat first.

```
select convert(datetime, OrderCreatedDate, 101) from table
```